# I want to show my wordpress posts into 2 rows and each rows will contain 2 posts each

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I am working on the default blog home page code. I have 4 posts in each blog page. Now they are showing vertically (one after another, up and down). I want to show these 4 posts into 2 rows and each row will contain 2 posts each. Here is the code of the blog page. I have used normal CSS to make them 2 columns.

```
<div class="amplify-content w-100 align-items-stretch order-0">
        <div class="content-list">
            <div class="mb-4"><strong class="text-uppercase">Category</strong> Graphic Design Lab</div>
            <div class="columncontent">
            <div class="row gutter-30 mb-4">
                <div class="col-12 col-md-6">

                    <main role="main">
                        <!-- section -->
                        <section class="bl">
                            <?php if (have_posts()): while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
                            <!-- article -->
                            <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
                                <!-- post thumbnail -->
                                <span class="blgimg"><?php if ( has_post_thumbnail()) : // Check if Thumbnail exists ?>
                                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>">
                                <?php the_post_thumbnail(); // Fullsize image for the single post ?>
                                </a>
                                <?php endif; ?></span>
                                <!-- /post thumbnail -->
                                <!-- post details -->
                                <br/>
                                <span class="date"><?php the_time('F j, Y'); ?> <?php the_time('g:i a'); ?></span>

                                <!-- /post details -->
                                <!-- post title -->
                                <h2 style="font-family: Journal-Regular;color: #d20a1e !important;text-transform: uppercase!important;" class="blgg">
                                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
                                </h2>
                                <!-- /post title -->
                                <!-- button -->
                                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="btn btn-outline-red rounded-0"><b>READ MORE</b></a><br/>
                                <!-- /button -->    
                                <!-- <span class="write" style="width:80% !important;"><?php the_excerpt(); // Dynamic Content ?></span> -->
                                <br/>          
                                <?php comments_template(); ?> 
                            </article>
                            <!-- /article -->
                            <?php endwhile; ?>
                            <?php get_the_posts_pagination(); ?> 
                            <?php else: ?>
                            <!-- article -->
                            <article>
                                <h1><?php _e( 'Sorry, nothing to display.', 'html5blank' ); ?></h1>
                            </article>
                            <!-- /article -->
                            <?php endif; ?>
                        </section>
                        <!-- /section -->
                    </main>
                </div>
                <div class="col-12 col-md-6">
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: This is more of a css question. Since it looks like you're already using bootstrap, maybe just change your article tag to  `<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" class="col-sm-6">` or something like that.

Comment: I am not sure what to do. can you please provide me a specific solution please?

Comment: What happened when you tried what I suggested?

Comment: nothing actually. It only reduced my content width. :(

Comment: I want to make it like
Blog one             Blog two
Blog three           Blog four

Comment: I opened the site. There's a number of things that would need to be fixed here to make it responsive. The fact that the images aren't all the same sizes means you'd probably want to write some css to keep it in the 2X2 pattern. Did you write this code yourself?

Comment: I have made all of the thumbnails size same. Now all of them are 250x250 px in size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright. Try this and lmk how it goes.

```
<div class="amplify-content w-100 align-items-stretch order-0">
    <div class="content-list">
        <div class="mb-4"><strong class="text-uppercase">Category</strong> Graphic Design Lab</div>
        <div>
        <div>
            <div class="col-12">

                <main role="main">
                    <!-- section -->
                    <section class="bl row">
                        <?php if (have_posts()): while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
                        <!-- article -->
                        <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
                            <!-- post thumbnail -->
                            <span class="blgimg"><?php if ( has_post_thumbnail()) : // Check if Thumbnail exists ?>
                            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>">
                            <?php the_post_thumbnail(); // Fullsize image for the single post ?>
                            </a>
                            <?php endif; ?></span>
                            <!-- /post thumbnail -->
                            <!-- post details -->
                            <br/>
                            <span class="date"><?php the_time('F j, Y'); ?> <?php the_time('g:i a'); ?></span>

                            <!-- /post details -->
                            <!-- post title -->
                            <h2 style="font-family: Journal-Regular;color: #d20a1e !important;text-transform: uppercase!important;" class="blgg">
                                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
                            </h2>
                            <!-- /post title -->
                            <!-- button -->
                                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="btn btn-outline-red rounded-0"><b>READ MORE</b></a><br/>
                            <!-- /button -->    
                            <!-- <span class="write" style="width:80% !important;"><?php the_excerpt(); // Dynamic Content ?></span> -->
                            <br/>          
                            <?php comments_template(); ?> 
                        </article>
                        <!-- /article -->
                        <?php endwhile; ?>
                        <?php get_the_posts_pagination(); ?> 
                        <?php else: ?>
                        <!-- article -->
                        <article>
                            <h1><?php _e( 'Sorry, nothing to display.', 'html5blank' ); ?></h1>
                        </article>
                        <!-- /article -->
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    </section>
                    <!-- /section -->
                </main>
            </div>
            <div class="col-12 col-md-6">
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Also, you should go into your index file and replace line 53 with `.blgimg img{width: 100%;}` instead of `.blgimg img{width: 250px;height:250px;}`

Comment: Thank you very much :D it works perfectly. thanks brother.